# Using TCP in SysLogHandler

Tags: python, logging, tcp

I am using

```
syslog_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(self.ip_address, 514), facility=self.facility)
```

to send play log files, and it is default by using UDP.

But now, I need to send TCP for a different log file, and keep UDP for any other existing logs. Is it possible to do that?

I was trying to simply add socktype to SysLogHandler like this:

```
syslog_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(self.ip_address, 514), facility=self.facility, socktype=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

but it doesn't work. Did I missed something?

Comment: True it should work as long as you have enabled tcp on syslog side.

Comment: Thank you. How to check if TCP is enabled on syslog side? I am just a python beginner

Comment: Hum, that is another story which is not even related to Python. Commonly you can check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to see if the tcp related part is commented or not.

Comment: Thank you. I tested on my local machine, it works. but I need to deploy my app to a VM, I didn't find such `rsyslog.conf` there. I can find a folder called `rsyslog.d` with only file `listen.conf` in it.

Comment: I've said, that's another story. You should start a new thread for this on superuser.